# How to copy all folders and sub-folders in a directory and without copying the files in the directory to another folder in your system

Tags: linux

Within my Downloads I have like 500 folders within it. Within most of those 500 folders I have other folders within them. I want to copy only the folders within this Downloads directory. This includes the folders within the folders.

In the end the objective is to have a have a new directory with like 500 folders and nearly 500 sub-folders and without a single file within them.

Can it be done?
I am ready to test this out.

Answer (score 1):

what you want is called copying directories structure , try `rsync`

`rsync -av --include='*/' --exclude='*' ~/Downloads ~/dls/`

or

`rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" ~/Downloads ~/dls/`

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

[`mtree`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mtree) is a good tool for this:

```
$ mkdir ~/newDir
$ mtree -cdp ~/Downloads | mtree -Up ~/newDir
```

The first invocation of `mtree` `c`reates a spec, referencing only `d`irectories, relative to the `p`ath `~/Downloads`.  That output gets piped to the second invocation of `mtree`, which `U`pdates the relative directory paths in `~/newDir`.  More specifically, in this case "updates" means that any missing entries are created.  Since the spec created from `~/Downloads` contains only directories, only the directory structure is created.

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` and `mtree` are great! Unfortunately, they are not always available. A bit more portable way to do it would be something like:

```bsh
(cd ~/Downloads && find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0) | (cd target_dir; xargs -0 mkdir -p)
```

Comment: You're right! However, both `find -print0` and `xargs -0` are supported on FreeBSD, Mac OS X, NetBSD, and Illumos, - not only in GNU. So it still looks quite portable to me. [AIX, HP-UX, and Oracle Solaris are out, however]. Edited my answer!

Comment: Ok, I was not aware of that. Thanks for the update!